# Enumerating over list with strings gives wrong results

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I was surprised to see that these two don't output the same results. Why is that?

For a list

```
numbers = ['01', '02', '03']
```

```py
>>> for val in numbers:
...     print(val)
01
02
03
```

while

```py
>>> for i, val in numbers:
...     print(val)
1
2
3
```

Comment: Maybe because you didn't `enumerate(numbers)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unintentionally unpacking your string into 2 variables:

```
a, b = "xy"
print(a)
print(b)
```

```
x
y
```

What you really want is actually `enumerate` them:

```
for i, val in enumerate(numbers):
    print(val)
```

```
01
02
03
```

Answer (score 1):

You're unpacking the string in two parts. First is assigned to `i` , and second to `val`.

You're doing something like this:

```
i, val = '01'
```

Instead try `enumerate` of python for enumeration.

See bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo(): a,b = 'ds'
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('ds')
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2         # <---
              4 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

The second loop unpacks each string into two chars. If you want to get something like

```
i val
0 01
1 02
2 03
```

then you should use `enumerate`.

```py
for i, val in enumerate(numbers):
    print(i, val)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are taking string element of list in one variable. It completely assigns that element to one variable.

```
numbers = ['01', '02', '03']
for val in numbers:
    print(val)
```

Here it gives you 1,2,3 because it's assigning string to two variables byte wise:

```
for i, val in numbers:
    print(val)
1
2
3
```

### For Example:

Like this, When you are doing

```
a,b = "89"
print('a =', a)
print('b =', b)
```

It returns a=8 and b=9. I think now it's clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Enumerate the for loop

```
for i, val in enumerate(numbers):
    print(val)
```